# Let $I = \langle x^2-3\rangle \subset \Bbb Q[x]$ and let $f=x-1 \in \Bbb Q[x]$. Show that $f+I$ is invertible in $\Bbb Q[x]/I$ and find the inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, quotient-group

> Let $I = \langle x^2-3\rangle \subset \Bbb Q[x]$ and let $f=x-1 \in \Bbb Q[x]$. Show that $f+I$ is invertible in $\Bbb Q[x]/I$ and find the inverse.

In $\Bbb Q[x]/I$ we have that $x^2-3=0$ so the identity is $x^2-2=1$. So in order to show that $f+I$ inverts I need to find $g+I$ such that $$(f+I)(g+I)=fg+I=1+I$$ that is I need to find a polynomial $g$ for which $(x-1)g(x)=x^2-2$.

I cannot figure this $g$ out. I don't think that $x^2-2$ has a nice factorization with $x-1$ as one of the factors even in $\Bbb Q[x]/I$?

Comment: You need to find some $g \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $(x-1) \, g(x) \equiv 1 \pmod{x^2 - 3}$, i.e. $(x-1) \, g(x) - 1 = (x^2 - 3) h(x)$ for some $h \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. You are implicitly assuming that $h = 1$, and that doesn't work.

Comment: The equation you're trying to solve is too strict. To find an inverse for $(x-1)$ in $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2-2)$, you need to find $g(x)$ so that $g(x)(x-1) \in  1+ (x^2 - 2)\mathbb Q[x]$, i.e. find $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ so that $g(x)(x-1) = 1+h(x)(x^2-2)$. Now use the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

In this ring, $x = \pm \sqrt 3$.  If $x=\sqrt 3$, then we want $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3 -1}$.  Rationalizing the denominator yields $\dfrac {\sqrt 3 + 1}{2}$, so try $g(x)=\dfrac {x+1}{2}$.

$$(x-1)\frac{x+1}{2}=\frac{x^2-1}{2}\equiv \frac{3-1}{2}\pmod{x^2-3}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

(Repeating comment here): You need to find some $g \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $(x-1) \, g(x) \equiv 1 \pmod{x^2 - 3}$, i.e.
$$
(x-1) \, g(x) - 1 = (x^2 - 3) h(x)
$$
for some $h \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. You are implicitly assuming that $h = 1$, and that doesn't work.

If you rearrange this equation to the form
$$
(x-1) \, g(x) - (x^2 - 3) h(x) = 1 
$$
it looks like [Bézout's identity](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) (in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ rather than in $\mathbb{Z}$). You can find such $g$ and $h$ if and only if
$$
\gcd(x-1, x^2-3) = 1,
$$
which you can probably see is true. Now, the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) gets you those coefficient polynomials.

Comment: Upon division I got that $$x^2-3=\left(x\:+\:1\right)\left(x-1\right)-2$$ i.e. $$(x+1)(x-1)+(x^2-3) = -2$$, but I'm missing this $1$ on the rhs?

Comment: Your one step away from it. Multiply by $-\tfrac12$ to obtain: 
$$
\bigl( \tfrac12 x + \tfrac12 \bigr)(x-1) - \tfrac12 (x^2 - 3) = 1, 
$$
i.e. $g(x) = \tfrac12 x + \tfrac12$ and $h(x) = \tfrac12$.

Comment: After rearranging back into a form that looks like a congruence 
$$
\bigl( \tfrac12 x + \tfrac12 \bigr) (x - 1) \equiv 1 \pmod{x^2 - 3}, 
$$
or in a form like it's in $\Bbb{Q}[x] / I$: 
$$
(x - 1 + I)^{-1} = \tfrac12 x + \tfrac12 + I.
$$